# Symfony Entity class as ManyToMany relation table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, many-to-many

This is common question i see. For now I had not find solution to make Entity from relation table used in M2M relation.

I want to ask you if you know that this will supported in future or if solution is still available.

This is what I tried to do.

> Entity that should represent relation table

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_research_keywords")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UsersResearchKeywords
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="researchkeywords_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $keyword;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get keyword
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getKeyword()
    {
        return $this->keyword;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

> Keywords Entity

```
...
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MainBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="keywords", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_research_keywords",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="researchkeywords_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $users;

...
```

> User Entity

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SciProfileBundle\Entity\ResearchKeywords", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_research_keywords",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="researchkeywords_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $keywords;
...
```

Comment: Why you don't simply use `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationships to get your results?

Comment: This not a solution in this case. I need M2M in this situation.

Comment: Just curiosity: why? An M:N relationship is exactly the same than a table with a 1:N to each of the original tables....

Comment: Just a thought:.. Why would you need the third table as an Entity? Sometimes people go too far with Doctrine. If you need to implement some complex query just use SQL. I'm just saying this based on some of my bad experiences.